# Dokuwiki - Hide Page Header Information

Tags: dokuwiki

In my Wiki, at the top of every page, I want the user to be able to download the page in either Word or PDF. The Word download has a command that allows you to NOT export a portion of the page. The PDF plugin I'm using (DW2PDF) does not have such a feature that I can find.

Is there a way to exclude a portion of the page? --OR-- Is there a way to tell the plugin I only want to print a certain area of the page?

Below is an example of what I'm experiencing -- I don't want to export the red and blue buttons to the PDF.

[image: Hide These Buttons]

Comment: You could hide it with CSS? If you look at this example for mPDF, it shows hiding sections on the page (by setting their 'display' property to 'none'): https://mpdf.github.io/real-life-examples/pdf-from-every-page-of-website.html

Comment: Make your comment an answer and I'll give you the credit.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the elements with CSS, e.g.

```
@media print {

  #redbutton, #bluebutton {
    display: none;
  }

}
```